# How to have just ONE instance running of an exe with 3.5 .NET framework and CE windows 5.0

Tags: c#-4.0

I've searched long and hard for an answer to my question and have found answers only to a class that does not exist in the 3.5 .NET frameworks version (and with CE Windows 5.0.)  Also, it's Visual C# with Visual Studio 2008.

When I try the following (using System.Threading)

```
 bool ok;
 Mutex myMutex = new Mutex();
 ok = Mutex(true,"scanner", out ok);
```

The compiler complains that the Mutex is a type, but used as a variable.    If I use a [STAThread], it also complains that it can't find it and I"m forced to use [MTAThread].

Are the classes for the mobile device type of c# programs the same for console based ones?  I'm somewhat new to this and the idea of how to declare, use, lock and everything you wanted to know about a mutex is making my head sore.  O.o  I suspect it's because the classes are different from the console verseions and the mobile versions.

It seems so simple, create a mutex, check for it's existance, if so then don't start a new exe instance.   That is all I want...just run one instance of any exe.  This is a mobile device thus it's a standalone and I never have to worry about anyone else using the .exe.  Just need to stop the user from tapping the start button 15 times and having 15 instances of the application running (then complain about low memory usage!)

I've read that a good way is to create a thread, lock it then check if the lock was successful to test if an instance of an exe is already running, close it if so else run the exe.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be to open a file for writing. Only one instance of the application could obtain this lock at a time. On startup, try and obtain a file handle for writing, if it fails, there must be another instance already running: exit immediately.

I think you can forget mutexes since we are talking about separate proceses here.